# How to get the content of the string being replaced with deface library, before the replacement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, deface

I want replace in *.erb files  tag using spree/deface library in rails. Replacing work fine. But I want get override string before it will override and get attribute "name" for example. I want use some attribute from old string in new string. For example: i want replace `<img class="deface" name="anyname" src="#"> on <h1>anyname</h1>`
"anyname" - different for every tag.

I dont find this feature in documentation. I try search something in library code, but my skill in ruby is not high. I try use <%= render_original %> placeholder for :surround action, but it not contain surrounding string. Maybe i am wrong.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.